# OData v4 Custom functions without namespace in WebAPI 2.2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

We want to use ODataV4 on WebAPI 2.2 for our new projects but there is one no-go: the url design.
We have to delivery json data and binary data (images) through our api.

Is there any possibility to avoid the namespace look of custom functions on OData routes?
`/odata/Customers/GetByName('Name')` instead of `/odata/Customers/CustomerService.GetByName('Name')`

And how should a response with binary data (jpeg images) be implemented with OData controllers?
A very ugly way would be to host OdataControllers and ApiControllers in one Project and use different url areas.

`/odata/Customers(1) -> OdataControllers
/api/Customers/1/ProfileImage -> ApiController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, please refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#06-01-custom-url-parsing.

Comment: Thanks. that looks great. But I always get the response
```{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://testapp.localhost/v1/Parts(432)/Rate'.","innererror":{
      "message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}```

Comment: Ok. I've changed 

```public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Rate([FromODataUri] long key)```

to

```public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Rate()```

then it works.
But how to reference the Parts Key?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, QianLi! You really helped!

```
HttpConfiguration config = …
config.EnableCaseInsensitive(caseInsensitive: true);
config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(unqualifiedNameCall: true);
config.EnableEnumPrefixFree(enumPrefixFree: true);
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel);
```